# How to change variable type when using @variable_Name?

Tags: mysql, variables

I tried to calculate percentage of certain inventories (with location id (loc_id) 3 and location id 4) out of all inventories. My attempt was as follow:

```
SELECT @totalInv := (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM inventory);

SELECT @locid3and4 := (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM inventory
                        WHERE loc_id=3 or loc_id=4);

SELECT @percentage := ((@locid3and4)DIV(@totalInv));
```

By manual calculation I know that the percentage should be 0.346. However, @percentage always returns 0 probably because its default data type is integer and mySQL rounds the value down from 0.346 to 0.

I tried to change the data type of column Quantity from Integer to DOUBLE/DECIMAL, @percentage however always returns 0. I am wondering is there a way to make alter data type of @percentage to make it display the true percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast to a decimal/floating point number, or just multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT @percentage := @locid3and4 * 1.0 / @totalInv;
```

Actually, that is overkill.  Just change `DIV` to `/`:

```
SELECT @percentage := @locid3and4 / @totalInv;
```

Why are you *choosing* integer division if you don't want it?